# isotope and images loaded layout not filling space full width

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry

I'm using Isotope and Images Loaded to a create full width grid, which has different height elements *(for this example I've kept them the same height)*. However I'm having an issue with the grid filling the space full width.

Even though the percents add up they don't line up and I cant figure out why. I'm trying to achieve the following:

| 50% | 30% | 20% |

However the div currently drops at 20% and looks like this:

| 50% | 30% |

| 20% | *<--- dropped down but should but above*

Below is my code:

```js
// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  percentPosition: true,
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
});
// layout Isotope after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress(function() {
  $grid.isotope();
});
```

```css
.grid {
  background: #EEE;
  max-width: 1800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* clearfix */

.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
}

.grid-item img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}


/* ---- grid-item ---- */

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 20%;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
  background: #D26;
}

.grid-item--width2 {
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}

.grid-item--width3 {
  width: 30%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4.1.4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3.0.5/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x387" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width3 ">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x387" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item ">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x387" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item ">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x387" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width3 ">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x387" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item ">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x387" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--width2 ">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x387" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues. Firstly, you're declaring columnWidth incorrectly so it's not actually doing anything with it. Should be like this as per the [Isotope documentation](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html#responsive-layouts):

```
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      percentPosition: true,
      masonry: {
          columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
      }
});
```

Next try splitting up the item and sizer CSS selectors like this. I've also changed the sizer to 10% width as I've previously encountered issues like this with layouts when grid-item widths were not in multiples of the grid-sizer.

```
.grid-sizer {
  width: 10%;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 20%;
}
```

The second row is still breaking but that's because the layout in your HTML is not even for that row.

Answer (score 0):

Not used Isotope before but I guess you need to add `layoutMode: 'fitRows'`

Here is the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gspdf00v/5/)

Comment: @probablybest stated that they have different height elements so fitRows isn't the best layout for that, masonry (default) is.